# how to use set(gca, …) function on button?

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

i am new in matlab so i can miss many things. I am trying to push picture up or down using button. but i am stuck. i want that when i press the button it should change the position. The ri_call( ...) function increments the row by mean it should shuffles the picture up a head when button "row increment" is pressed.

so here is my code:

```
 function ri_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to ri (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
handles.r =  handles.r -1;
    I= imread('pout.tif');    %picture reading
    imshow(I);
    I(handles.h:handles.r,handles.wid:handles.col,:) = 0;
    I= set(gca,'Position',get(gca,'Position') + [handles.r handles.c 0 0]);   % ????? not working on button
    imshow(I);
    % Update handles structure
    guidata(hObject, handles);

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't get an output from `set`.  Instead of

```
I = set(gca,...)
```

which overwrites your image, just do

```
set(gca,...)
```

Also, you need to *set the units* to do `set` correctly.  Assuming `handles.r` and `handles.c` have pixels:

```
set(gca,'Units','Pixels')
set(gca,'Position',...)
```

---

If you are looking to move the mask, introduce x,y offsets to the mask:

```
I(yoffset+(handles.h:handles.r),xoffset+(handles.wid:handles.col),:) = 0;
```

But I would interpret `handles.h` as a height, `handles.wid` as a width and `handles.r` as the starting y coordinate of the corner of the box and `handles.col` as the starting x coordinate of the box. This interpretation would yield the command:

```
I((1:handles.h)+handles.r+yoffset-1,(1:handles.wid)+handles.col+xoffset-1,:) = 0;
```

Comment: @user3508182 See update.  You need to set the units to pixels.

Comment: these 3 lines i hve added but image gets invisible. no change. kindly correct me if i am doing wrong. set(gca,'Units',handles.r);
     set(gca,'Units',handles.col);
    set(gca,'Position',get(gca,'Position') + [handles.r handles.col 0 0]);

Comment: @user3508182 No, you need to literally set units to the string `'Pixels'`, not actual pixel values. Copy exactly the line in the answer (`set(gca,'Units','Pixels')`). This says that you can set the `Position` or other properties in terms of pixels, instead of normalized units.

Comment: the background picture is moving, i want to move this box picture: I(handles.h:handles.r,handles.wid:handles.col,:) = 0; ?? any idea???

Comment: @user3508182 The position property moves the whole axis. If you want to mask out a different part of the image, the axis position is unrelated. You have to change the offsets in the command `I(yoffset+(handles.h:handles.r),xoffset+(handles.wid:handles.col),:) = 0;` But what does `handles.col` and `handles.r` represent?

Comment: handles.col is gettig the value when button is pressed so it is a hanlder which updates the hanlde.

Comment: @user3508182 I mean what is the meaning of `handles.col`.  See my new update, which explains my interpretation of the fields of `handles` along with a new command for masking.

Comment: yes yes. r means row h means hight col mean column for changng position i am using row and column

Comment: height means increase the lenght or height of picture and width mean increase the depth of picture